# PHPStorm ignores file after file watcher was triggered

Tags: sass, phpstorm, file-watcher

PHPStorm (9.0.2) is ignoring my .scss files **once the file watcher was triggered**. They appear to be invisible in the file structure, but still are there (if you look with another program).
There are no scopes or ignored files set up.

After clearing the cache and restarting, the files are visible again. But as soon as the File Watcher runs one, they are invisible again.

Does anyone have an idea where this come from and how to fix that?

[image: Screenshot of File Watcher Settings]

Answer (score 1):

Please remove the `$FileName$:` from '`Output paths to refresh`' and then invalidate caches (File/Invalidate caches, restart) - this should solve your issue